# "assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast -wint-conversion"

Tags: c, syntax-error

I am new to c language and I wanted to make a calculator so I wrote this code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
    int x,y,z;
    char m;
    printf("enter the first number");
    scanf("%d",&x);
    printf("enter the second number");
    scanf("%d",&y);
    printf("enter the math operator");
    scanf("%c",&m);
if (m == '+')
{
    z=x+y;
    printf("the answer is %d",z);

}
else if(m == '-')
{
    z=x-y;
    printf("the answer is %d",z);
}
else
{
    printf("wrong symbol");
}
    }
```

when I run the program it will ignore

```
scanf("%c",&m);
```

and

```
if (m == '+')
{
    z=x+y;
    printf("the answer is %d",z);

}
else if(m == '-')
{
    z=x-y;
    printf("the answer is %d",z);
}
```

and it will go straight to

```
else
    {
        printf("wrong symbol");
    }
```

and it shows like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RmsWm.jpg
please help.

Comment: The title is completely unrelated to the code, and there is no real question. Please read the [tour] and [ask].

Comment: @C_Elegans I agree, but this question as it stands should be closed as *unclear what you're asking*.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to flush the stream entry stdin because some char are still in stdin when you call `scanf("%c",&m);`. And since it looks only for one char ... It directly takes the first char already in stdin (`'\n'`).

Insert this portable code to flush stdin before call scanf :

```
int c;
while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);
```

Hope this help !